# Find a child by id in JS Object and push to it

Tags: javascript, object, search

I have an object like this, I want to find a child by id and push a new child to it.

```
{
'id': '234567869',
'name': 'Lao Lao',
'title': 'general manager',
'children': [{
    'id': '467876756634',
    'name': 'Bo Miao',
    'title': 'department manager'
}, {
    'id': '2345666078',
    'name': 'Su Miao',
    'title': 'department manager',
    'children': [{
        'id': '898735342',
        'name': 'Tie Hua',
        'title': 'senior engineer'
    }, {
        'id': '7697347548',
        'name': 'Hei Hei',
        'title': 'senior engineer',
        'children': [{
            'id': '123415640',
            'name': 'Pang Pang',
            'title': 'engineer'
        }, {
            'id': '1237450976',
            'name': 'Xiang Xiang',
            'title': 'UE engineer'
        }]
    }]
}, {
    'id': '6968756535',
    'name': 'Yu Jie',
    'title': 'department manager'
}, {
    'id': '236448654',
    'name': 'Chun Miao',
    'title': 'department manager'
}, {
    'id': '356898765',
    'name': 'Yu Tie',
    'title': 'department manager'
}]}
```

I want to add a child to the object with the id of "898735342" or "234567869".

I used this recursive function, but not working. this is supposed to search by "id" in our object and push the "newObj" to it as the child.

```
var newObj = {
    'id': '999999999',
    'name': 'new name',
    'title': 'new added child',
};

function findNodeAndUpdate(idToFind, bigObjectToSearch, newObj) {
    var i, currentChild, result;
    if (idToFind == bigObjectToSearch.id) {
        bigObjectToSearch.children.push(newObj);
        return true;
    } else {
        // Use a for loop instead of forEach to avoid nested functions
        // Otherwise "return" will not work properly
        for (i = 0; i < bigObjectToSearch.children.length; i += 1) {
            currentChild = bigObjectToSearch.children[i];
            // Search in the current child
            result = findNodeAndUpdate(idToFind, currentChild, newObj);
            // Return the result if the node has been found
            if (result !== false) {
                bigObjectToSearch.children.push(newObj);
                return true;
            }
        }
        // The node has not been found and we have no more options
        return false;
    }
}
```

Another function which still is not working:

```
function findObjectById(root, id) {
    if (root.id == id){
        return root;
    }
    if (root.children) {
        for (var k in root.children) {
            if (root.children[k].id == id) {
                return root.children[k];
            }
            else if (root.children.length) {
                return findObjectById(root.children[k], id);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: hint: traverse the whole tree once and store all nodes in an object by their id. this makes further lookups by id a simple `node = nodesById[id]`

Comment: @Thomas I added a new function to my question (findObjectById) which does the exact same thing you mentioned, but it's not working and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code:

```js
var obj = {
    'id': '234567869',
    'name': 'Lao Lao',
    'title': 'general manager',
    'children': [{
        'id': '467876756634',
        'name': 'Bo Miao',
        'title': 'department manager'
    }, {
        'id': '2345666078',
        'name': 'Su Miao',
        'title': 'department manager',
        'children': [{
            'id': '898735342',
            'name': 'Tie Hua',
            'title': 'senior engineer'
        }, {
            'id': '7697347548',
            'name': 'Hei Hei',
            'title': 'senior engineer',
            'children': [{
                'id': '123415640',
                'name': 'Pang Pang',
                'title': 'engineer'
            }, {
                'id': '1237450976',
                'name': 'Xiang Xiang',
                'title': 'UE engineer'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        'id': '6968756535',
        'name': 'Yu Jie',
        'title': 'department manager'
    }, {
        'id': '236448654',
        'name': 'Chun Miao',
        'title': 'department manager'
    }, {
        'id': '356898765',
        'name': 'Yu Tie',
        'title': 'department manager'
    }]
};

var newObj = {
    'id': '999999999',
    'name': 'new name',
    'title': 'new added child',
};

function findNodeAndUpdate(idToFind, bigObjectToSearch, newObj) {
    var i, currentChild, result;
    if (idToFind == bigObjectToSearch.id) {
        bigObjectToSearch.children = bigObjectToSearch.children || [];
        bigObjectToSearch.children.push(newObj);
        return true;
    } else if (bigObjectToSearch.children) {
        for (i = 0; i < bigObjectToSearch.children.length; i += 1) {
            currentChild = bigObjectToSearch.children[i];
            // Search in the current child
            if(findNodeAndUpdate(idToFind, currentChild, newObj)){
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

findNodeAndUpdate('898735342', obj, newObj);

console.log(obj);
```

To delete the obj,

```
function deleteNode(idToFind, bigObjectToSearch) {
    var i, currentChild, result;
    if (idToFind == bigObjectToSearch.id) {
        return true;
    } else if (bigObjectToSearch.children) {
        for (i = 0; i < bigObjectToSearch.children.length; i += 1) {
            currentChild = bigObjectToSearch.children[i];
            // Search in the current child
            if(deleteNode(idToFind, currentChild)){
                //delete bigObjectToSearch.children[i];
                bigObjectToSearch.children.splice(i,1);
                break;
            };
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: it has an error, it always adds the new object to the root object even if we're updating the nested children.

Comment: what if I want to delete a node by it's id. for example, if I want to delete the node with the id of "6968756535"?

Comment: I have edited the ans to delete the node. Please try :)

Comment: please try now :)

Comment: it set's the children to null, I want this to be removed. is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163784/discussion-between-jasmin-makasana-and-behz4d).

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code.

```
var searchObj = {
    'id': '234567869',
    'name': 'Lao Lao',
    'title': 'general manager',
    'children': [{
        'id': '467876756634',
        'name': 'Bo Miao',
        'title': 'department manager'
    }, {
        'id': '2345666078',
        'name': 'Su Miao',
        'title': 'department manager',
        'children': [{
            'id': '898735342',
            'name': 'Tie Hua',
            'title': 'senior engineer'
        }, {
            'id': '7697347548',
            'name': 'Hei Hei',
            'title': 'senior engineer',
            'children': [{
                'id': '123415640',
                'name': 'Pang Pang',
                'title': 'engineer'
            }, {
                'id': '1237450976',
                'name': 'Xiang Xiang',
                'title': 'UE engineer'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        'id': '6968756535',
        'name': 'Yu Jie',
        'title': 'department manager'
    }, {
        'id': '236448654',
        'name': 'Chun Miao',
        'title': 'department manager'
    }, {
        'id': '356898765',
        'name': 'Yu Tie',
        'title': 'department manager'
    }]
};

function findNodeAndUpdate(bigObjectToSearch, idToFind, newObj) {
    if (idToFind) {
        findNodeAndUpdate.searchValue = idToFind;
    }
    if (newObj) {
        findNodeAndUpdate.pushValue = newObj;
    }
    if (isArray(bigObjectToSearch)) {
        traverseArray(bigObjectToSearch)
    } else if ((typeof bigObjectToSearch === 'object') && (bigObjectToSearch !== null)) {
        traverseObject(bigObjectToSearch)
    } else {

    }
}

function traverseArray(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(data) {
        findNodeAndUpdate(data)
    })
}

function traverseObject(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key === "id" && obj[key] == findNodeAndUpdate.searchValue) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
                    obj.children.push(findNodeAndUpdate.pushValue);
                } else {
                    obj["children"] = [];
                    obj.children.push(findNodeAndUpdate.pushValue);

                }
                break;
            } else {
                findNodeAndUpdate(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}

function isArray(o) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object Array]'
}
findNodeAndUpdate(searchObj, "898735342", {
    'id': '999999999',
    'name': 'new name',
    'title': 'new added child',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,the core is the loop,and when you pass objects as arguments,whatever changes happen to the objects in the function or loop,it will changes the objects outside the function,that is the most important

```
let oldObj = {
    "id": "234567869",
    "name": "Lao Lao",
    "title": "general manager",
    "children": [{
        "id": "467876756634",
        "name": "Bo Miao",
        "title": "department manager"
    }, {
        "id": "2345666078",
        "name": "Su Miao",
        "title": "department manager",
        "children": [{
            "id": "898735342",
            "name": "Tie Hua",
            "title": "senior engineer"
        }, {
            "id": "7697347548",
            "name": "Hei Hei",
            "title": "senior engineer",
            "children": [{
                "id": "123415640",
                "name": "Pang Pang",
                "title": "engineer"
            }, {
                "id": "1237450976",
                "name": "Xiang Xiang",
                "title": "UE engineer"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "6968756535",
        "name": "Yu Jie",
        "title": "department manager"
    }, {
        "id": "236448654",
        "name": "Chun Miao",
        "title": "department manager"
    }, {
        "id": "356898765",
        "name": "Yu Tie",
        "title": "department manager"
    }]
};

let result = {
    "id": "234567869",
    "name": "Lao Lao",
    "title": "general manager",
    "children": [{
        "id": "467876756634",
        "name": "Bo Miao",
        "title": "department manager"
    }, {
        "id": "2345666078",
        "name": "Su Miao",
        "title": "department manager",
        "children": [{
            "id": "898735342",
            "name": "Tie Hua",
            "title": "senior engineer"

        }, {
            "id": "7697347548",
            "name": "Hei Hei",
            "title": "senior engineer",
            "children": [{
                "id": "123415640",
                "name": "Pang Pang",
                "title": "engineer"
            }, {
                "id": "1237450976",
                "name": "Xiang Xiang",
                "title": "UE engineer"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "6968756535",
        "name": "Yu Jie",
        "title": "department manager"
    }, {
        "id": "236448654",
        "name": "Chun Miao",
        "title": "department manager"
    }, {
        "id": "356898765",
        "name": "Yu Tie",
        "title": "department manager"
    }, {
        'id': '999999999',
        'name': 'new name',
        'title': 'new added child',
    }]
};

var newObj = {
    'id': '999999999',
    'name': 'new name',
    'title': 'new added child',
};

function findIdAppendObj(newObj, oldObj, idToFind) {

    if (oldObj.id === idToFind) {

        if (oldObj.children) {
            oldObj.children.push(newObj);
        } else {
            oldObj.children = [newObj];
        }

        return oldObj;

    } else {
        if (oldObj.children) {
            oldObj.children.forEach(function(child) {
                findIdAppendObj(newObj, child, idToFind);
            });
        }
    }

    return oldObj;

}

let testResult = findIdAppendObj(newObj, oldObj, '234567869');
console.log(JSON.stringify(testResult) === JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I added a new function to my question (findObjectById) which does the exact same thing you mentioned

not exactly

> but it's not working and I can't figure out what's wrong.

this condition `root.children.length` is always `true` at that point, so you never get past the first child before returning.

But what I meant was more like this:

```
let root = //...
let nodesById = Object.create(null);

//map nodes by id
(function traverse(node){
  nodesById[id] = node;
  if(node.children)
    node.children.forEach(traverse);
})( root );
```

and your lookup boils down to this

```
function findObjectById(id) {
  return nodesById[id];
}
```